# Private and Public Key Concept in RSA

Tags: encryption

I am actually building a file encryption solution which shall have following salient features:

**ENCRYPTION SIDE**

1. Firstly, I have to Hash the file with SHA-256 and store that hash in a separate file.
2. Afterwards, I have to encrypt that file using private key of sender.
3. A symmetric key will be generated for AES Algorithm.
4. I then have to encrypt the actual file with that symmetric key.
5. Finally, that symmetric key will be encrypted with public key of the receiver.

**DECRYPTION SIDE**

1. Decryption of hash file with public key of sender.
2. Decryption of encrypted asymmetric key with private key of receiver.
3. Decryption of that actual file with symmetric key.
4. Hashing the actual file again
5. Compare the hash generated with the hash provided by sender to validate content.

Now, I that is the complete stuff I need to implement, However, I have few queries pertaining to the keys actually; which are not clarified after surfing many web-sites.

**QUERIES**

1. What does actually meant by the private key of sender? I know, I shall have to implement it with RSA Algorithm; which works with key pair. If I (sender) will encrypt the file with public key generated in key pair that how the private key for the receiver will be generated? Is this the same key generated under key pair?

if yes then do we have to provide that key to the receive?
if no then how the data will be decrypted by the receiver? since the message is encrypted under my own key pair generated...

2. How can we share the relevant keys and hashes with the receiver? Since, emails and other platforms are public and shall not be used for sharing confidential data.

Please an easy explanation will be very helpful for me, I am confused with these above mentioned terms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> What does actually meant by the private key of sender? I know, I shall have to implement it with RSA Algorithm; which works with key pair. If I (sender) will encrypt the file with public key generated in key pair that how the private key for the receiver will be generated? Is this the same key generated under key pair?

In very old documents or by very confused people, this is the way that they talk about signature generation. Normally the hashes won't be stored in a file though, unless a Merkle tree is used instead of direct hashing.

> if yes then do we have to provide that key to the receive? if no then how the data will be decrypted by the receiver? since the message is encrypted under my own key pair generated...

The public key should be distributed to the other party in any way that the public key can be trusted (to be from the sender). Then the sender's public key can be used to verify the signature created over the original file.

> How can we share the relevant keys and hashes with the receiver? Since, emails and other platforms are public and shall not be used for sharing confidential data.

That's up to you. Generally a trusted third party is used together with X.509 certificates. The whole thing together is called Public Key Infrasture or, even more broadly, key management.